# Pythonic way of checking parameter is an integer and setting a default value if no parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I want to get a GET parameter in my Flask app. I would like to check that this parameter is an integer if it was submitted.

- If it was not submitted I would like to set a default value.
- If it was submitted but is invalid, I would like to throw an error

I came up with the following code which works but seems ugly and unpythonic to me. What is the most pythonic way of doing this?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page') or 0
    try:
        page = int(page)
    except:
        return abort(500)
```

Comment: Note that `abort()` raises an exception, the `return` statement itself is never reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the [`request.args.get()` method](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) to test for your type, and set a default:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page', type=int, default=0)
```

If type conversion fails, the default is used. In a web environment that's a much, *much* better idea than to raise a 500 response (which is reserved for *server* errors, while not providing a valid page number is really a client error).

`request.args.get()` will otherwise *never raise an exception*; it returns `None` instead if no other default was set. If you *must* have an exception on type conversion, you are stuck with your approach, but I'd return a [*400 Bad Request* error code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors) instead:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    page_str = request.args.get('page', default=0)
    try:
        page = int(page_str)
    except ValueError:
        abort(400)
```

`abort(...)` raises an exception, no need to use `return` there. Because an exception is raised, you could make that whole block of 4 lines a separate function:

```
def convert_or_400(value, type):
    """Convert a value to the given type, or raise a 400 client error"""
    try:
        return type(value)
    except ValueError:
        abort(400)
```

Now the route becomes:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    page = convert_or_400(request.args.get('page', default=0), int)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def index():
    page = input("enter the value")
    try:
        if (page != ""):
            page = int(page)
        else:            
            page = 0
        print("Input value..",page)
    except:
        print("wrong value given.Input numeric value")       
index()
```

A simple way

Comment: Several problems here: The question is tagged Flask, so `input()` is not going to work for a web client. The original approach of using `or 0` was much better than testing for an empty string explicitly, and making the `else` block redundant. Do **not** use a blanket `except` statement (the OP made the same mistake), you are now catching keyboard interrupts, memory errors and generator exits too. This isn't pokemon, you don't want to catch them all. Catch *just the `ValueError` exception*.